# Flex - Calling a public method located outside of the main view

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mobile, adobe

New to Flex, I'm trying to figure out a way to call a public method declared on a view which is the "firstView" of the application. How do I get a reference?

**Main View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160"  firstView="views.loaderView" creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void{
                //how do I access this method?
                        loaderView.setLoaderMsg("My Message");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

**Loader View**

```
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="rg"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="15" paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="15" gap="15" 
                          horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:BusyIndicator/>  
    <s:Label id="loaderMsg" text="Loading..." />

</s:View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all children defined in MXML are in the public namespace, so you can easily access it via dot notation. That's the easiest way for the first steps in Flex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                            applicationDPI="160"
                            firstView="views.loaderView"
                            creationComplete="init()">
  <fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
  </fx:Declarations>
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      private function init():void{
        trace(navigator.activeView);
        // const first:loaderView = navigator.activeView as loaderViewM
        // first.loaderMsg.text = "My Message";
      }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Comment: mmm...that did not work "Access of possibly undefined property loaderMsg through a reference with static type Class"

Comment: loaderView is the class name, not the instance name?

Comment: still no go, "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: Just made an edit, please check again. Use the navigator to get te active view.

Comment: I havent't worked with Flex mobile yet. Could you indicate if navigator.activeView exists? If so, first does, loaderMsg not. You could add an event handler for FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE on first in init and then set the message in the event handler.

Comment: it does exist, 
trace -> "LPChat0.ViewNavigatorApplicationSkin2.navigator.ViewNavigatorSkin4.contentGroup.LoaderView15" the app falls on the declaration of the const

Comment: Please check my latest version. The const should be at least initialized with null, and the break.

Comment: Cool, that works ... it needs to be done on the creationComplete handler. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, sorry for the long chitchat here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myPublicFunction

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is that a common practice? What is the best approach? I find both solutions abit hackey

Comment: The topLevelApplication is s:ViewNavigatorApplication, so wont help with accessing variables or methods of view that have not been loaded. Active view is preferable imo